# Trying to post array in my mongodb collection from POST API in node.js using mongoose and express

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my **orders model**.

```
const Order = mongoose.model('Order', new mongoose.Schema({
    saleprice: {type: Number},
    discount: {type: Number},
    products : [{
        type: productSchema
    }]
}));
```

This is my **products model**

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    price: {type: Number, required: true},
    category: {type: String, required: true}
});
```

Now I want to **post multiple products in single order post API call**; Currently using this approach but this is not working for arrays. How I can add multiple products just by sending multiple productIds in JSON format.

```
router.post('/', async(req, res) =>{

    const product = await Product.findById(req.body.productId);
    if(!product) 
        return res.status(400).send('Invalid product.');

    const order =new Order({        
        saleprice: "790",
        discount: "100",
        products: [{
            _id: product._id,
            name: product.name,
            price: (product.price).toString(),
            category: product.category
        }]
    });
    await order.save();
    res.send(order);

});
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(req.body)` above your `Product.findById` and show us the output?

Comment: *`console.log(req.body.productId)`

Comment: `console.log(req.body.productId);       = 5edc2a837c429c1f647ac6f5 ` doing this before `Product.findbyID` will display id which was given through our JSON 
`{
 "productId": "5edc2a837c429c1f647ac6f5"
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to think of it in modular terms and approach it step by step.

You are currently trying to do it all at once. Break it into bits.

**Mongoose has a method called populate(), which lets you reference documents in other collections.**

Population is the process of automatically replacing the specified paths in the document with document(s) from other collection(s). We may populate a single document, multiple documents, a plain object, multiple plain objects, or all objects returned from a query.

Here is an example:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const personSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  stories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

const Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const storySchema = Schema({
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
  title: String,
  fans: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]
});

const Story = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
```

From the example you can see that you are not doing the right way as you have not set a reference between Order and Product.

You order schema can set a reference to product like so:

```
...
products : [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'
    }]
...
```

The code above defines an association between the **Order** and **Product** database schemas. Like I mentioned in the beginning, you have to take a modular approach. From what I can see about your Project, you create Products first and then a customer creates an Order per Product. You have to the create a Products. When this is done, you can then reference a particular product by Id when you are creating an order. Like so:

```
...
const order =new Order({        
        saleprice: "790",
        discount: "100",
        products: req.body.productId
    });
...
```

You can read more on Mongoose Populate method [here.](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: I am not able to use `populate()` in my **POST API** to populate many products in a single order. Can you write any example so I can better understand.

Comment: That is fine. I will create a github gist and share with you.

Comment: Will appreciate you.